# Convergence in measure can be characterized by convergence in a suitable metric

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The question is the following:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space. Let $f_n:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of measurable functions. Suppose that there exists a measurable function $f$ such that for every finite measurable set $D \in \mathcal{A}$, we have
>   $$
> \int_D \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} d\lambda \to 0
> $$
>   (a) Prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure.
>
> (b) Suppose that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure. Using the fact that if every subsequence of $f_n$ has a further subsequence that converges almost everywhere (Riesz Theorem), prove that
>   $$
> \int_D \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} d\lambda \to 0
> $$

I proved the part (a) with the Chebyshev's inequality, but I can't relate the Riesz Theorem to the result. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n \to f$ a.e, then
$$\frac{\vert f_n - f \vert}{1 + \vert f_n - f \vert}$$
converges to $0$ a.e. and is uniformly bounded by $1$, which is integrable on $D$ since $D$ has finite measure. Therefore
$$\int_D \frac{\vert f_n - f \vert}{1 + \vert f_n - f \vert}d\lambda \to 0$$
by the dominated convergence theorem.

By the Riesz theorem, if $f_n \to f$ in measure, then every subsequence of $f_n$ has a subsequence which converges to $f$ pointwise a.e. Then by the work above, this means that every subsequence of
$$\int_D \frac{\vert f_n - f \vert}{1 + \vert f_n - f \vert} d\lambda$$
has a subsequence which converges to $0$, which means that
$$\int_D \frac{\vert f_n - f \vert}{1 + \vert f_n - f \vert}d\lambda \to 0.$$

Comment: This is actually what I thought!!!! But does it really work? It looks so trivial to me that I highly doubted my understanding.